# Maximum call stack size exceeded( in Nuxt + Firebase Project)

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm currently creating an authentication feature in Nuxt and Firebase.

The login and logout process itself can be done and the header display changes accordingly, but there is an error in console when I press the login button.

### Error content (in console)

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
```

### code

Header.vue(This is the page containing the login button.)↓

```
googleLogin () {
      const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
      auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then(res => {
          this.dialogAuthVisible = false
          this.$store.dispatch('auth/setUser',res.user)
        }).catch(e => console.log(e))
 }
```

store/auth.js↓

```
export const strict = false

export const state = () => ({
  user: null
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_USER (state, payload) {
    state.user = payload
  }
}

export const actions = {
  setUser ({ commit }, user) {
    commit('SET_USER',user)
  }
}

export const getters = {
  isAuthenticated (state) {
    return !!state.user
  }
}
```

default.vue↓

```
mounted () {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      const { uid, displayName, photoURL} = user
      if (user) {
        this.$store.dispatch('auth/setUser', { uid, displayName, photoURL})
      } else {
        this.$store.dispatch('auth/setUser', null)
      }
    })
  }
```

If there's any information I'm missing, please let me know ️.
Please teach me how to do this ️.

Comment: this error usually comes from an infinte recursion. if you can provide a jsfiddle or codepen with reproduction, I can take a deeper look

Comment: How is defined auth variable?

Comment: thank you comments. this is auth variable const auth = firebase.auth()

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this code lines :

```
export const mutations = {
  SET_USER (state, payload) {
    state.user = payload
  }
}

export const actions = {
  setUser ({ commit }, user) {
    commit('SET_USER',user)
  }
}
```

There is a loop between this mutations and actions

Comment: thank you!! 
I've thought about it, but I don't know how to fix it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the entire payload into the store object, I just picked the fields I needed, and that resolved the problem for me.

Before:

```
  AUTH_STATUS_CHANGED ({commit}, data: any): any {
    if (data && data.authUser) {
      commit('SetAuthUser', data.authUser);
    } else {
      commit('SetAuthUser', null);
    }
  }
```

After:

```
AUTH_STATUS_CHANGED ({commit}, data: any): any {
    if (data && data.authUser) {
      const user = data.authUser;
      commit('SetAuthUser', {
        uid: user.uid,
        email: user.email,
        emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
        displayName: user.displayName,
        isAnonymous: user.isAnonymous,
        photoURL: user.photoURL,
        stsTokenManager: user.stsTokenManager,
        createdAt: user.createdAt,
        lastLoginAt: user.lastLoginAt,
        apiKey: user.apiKey,
      });
    } else {
      commit('SetAuthUser', null);
    }
  }
```

Inside the mutation, just add the value received from the mutation payload.